# counter in runnable 'local variables referenced from an inner class must be final or effectively final'

Tags: java, minecraft, runnable, bukkit

I need a counter inside of my runnable, I tried writing something that looks like

```
public class Foo {
  private class Bar {
    public void barMethod() {
      int counter = 0;
      Bar instance = this;
      BukkitTask barTask = new BukkitRunnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
          if (counter == 5) {
            this.cancel();
            return;
          }
          instance.doStuff(); // don't worry it exists
          counter++;
        }
      }.runTaskTimer(this.plugin, 0L, 2L);
    }
  }
}
```

However, trying to compile it results in the error

```
local variables referenced from an inner class must be final or effectively final
```

So I see that the problem is I try to update the `counter` variable from inside the runnable.

However, that leaves me clueless as to how I can have a counter on the runnable.

How can I make sure the runnable only runs maximum 5 times?

Comment: You could make `counter` an instance variable

Comment: @Flaom that works too. replacing with an array as Alexey suggests seems faster/easier though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The standard workaround is to replace with a single-element array:

```
public class Foo {
  private class Bar {
    public void barMethod() {
      int[] counter = new int[] { 0 };
      Bar instance = this;
      BukkitTask barTask = new BukkitRunnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
          if (counter[0] == 5) {
            this.cancel();
            return;
          }
          instance.doStuff(); // don't worry it exists
          counter[0]++;
        }
      }.runTaskTimer(this.plugin, 0L, 2L);
    }
  }
}
```

The variable itself is never reassigned, so it's effectively final.

Answer (score 1):

You can fix this error this way:

```
public class Foo {
    private class Bar {
        public void barMethod() {
            Bar instance = this;
            BukkitTask barTask = new BukkitRunnable() {
                int counter = 0;

                @Override
                public void run() {
                    if (counter == 5) {
                        this.cancel();
                        return;
                    }
                    instance.doStuff(); // don't worry it exists
                    counter++;
                }
            }.runTaskTimer(this.plugin, 0L, 2L);
        }
    }
}
```

Sincerely